# Why is there a difference when calling argparse.parse_args() or .parse_args(sys.argv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have created the following argument parser in my python code.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('projectPath')
parser.add_argument('-project')
parser.add_argument('-release')
parser.add_argument('--test', default=False, action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and I'm executing my program the following way.

```
myProgram.py /path/to/file -project super --test
```

it works fine if I use the sysntax above with

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

However if I take and use the sys.argv as input

```
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)
```

The parser is suddenly picky about the order of the arguments and I get the unrecognized argument error.

```
usage: fbu.py [-h] [-project PROJECT] [-release RELEASE] [--test] projectPath
fbu.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /path/to/file
```

As I can see from the error and also using the -h argument. The path argument must be last and the error makes sense in the last example. 
But why does it not care about the order in the first example ?

EDIT: I'm using python version 3.4.3

Comment: Try `parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])`

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` is used as the default `prog` - program name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sys.argv` contains the script name as the first item, i.e. `myProgram.py`. That argument takes the spot of  `projectPath`. Now there's one additional positional argument `/path/to/file`, which can't be matched to any arguments, hence the error.

Calling `parse_args` without arguments `ArgumentParser` is clever enough to omit the script name from being parsed. But when explicitly passing an array of arguments, it can't do that and will parse everything.

Comment: ah I see. Thank you. Apparently I did not read the documentation well enough.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from looking at [the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bb9fc884a838/Lib/argparse.py#l1733) for `parse_known_args` (which is called by `parse_args`):

```
if args is None:
    # args default to the system args
    args = _sys.argv[1:]
```

When you don't provide the arguments explicitly, Python removes the first item from `.argv` (which is the name of the script). If you pass the arguments manually, you must do this yourself:

```
parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

This isn't explicitly covered in the documentation, but note that [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#beyond-sys-argv) doesn't include a script name when calling `parse_args` manually:

> #### Beyond `sys.argv`
>
> Sometimes it may be useful to have an `ArgumentParser` parse arguments
>   other than those of `sys.argv`. This can be accomplished by passing a
>   list of strings to `parse_args()`. This is useful for testing at the
>   interactive prompt:
>
> ```
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> >>> parser.add_argument(
> ...     'integers', metavar='int', type=int, choices=xrange(10),
> ...  nargs='+', help='an integer in the range 0..9')
> >>> parser.add_argument(
> ...     '--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const', const=sum,
> ...   default=max, help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')
> >>> parser.parse_args(['1', '2', '3', '4'])
> Namespace(accumulate=<built-in function max>, integers=[1, 2, 3, 4])
> >>> parser.parse_args('1 2 3 4 --sum'.split())
> Namespace(accumulate=<built-in function sum>, integers=[1, 2, 3, 4])
> ```

The advantage of passing the arguments manually is that it makes it easier to test the parsing functionality, as you can pass in a list of appropriate arguments rather than trying to patch `sys.argv`.